# How do I get a certain villager?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*, is there a way to gain a particular villager?

For example, if I want Benjamin to join my town, how do I increase the chance of that villager moving in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough room in your town for new villagers (less than 10 villagers living in your town) you can force any neighbor into your town - so long as you know someone else who happens to have that villager, packed up and ready to move on their move date. If you visit the town the desired villager is living in, and go to the villager's home, there will be an option to tell them to move in upon talking to them.

As far as random move-ins, however, its totally random. However, I do believe if you have an abundance of a certain personality type, and are lacking in others, neighbors of the overpopulated personality type will typically be your "movers," and the personalities you have none of, or very little of, will begin moving in. Although this is just personal experience, as I do villager cycle in a diversity of different towns. I don't know if others have found this to be true as well in their towns.

There was a point that I had 5 Cranky villagers in my town, and every single day one of them would ping me asking to move. I had 0 Snooty villagers, and when I finally let one of the Cranky ones go, Baabara, the Snooty sheep came in. I then let another Cranky go, and I got a Lazy villager, Punchy, whereas I had 0 Lazy villagers prior to his arrival. Since then, whenever I don't force-move villagers, and I just rapidly cycle my town, I seem to find this pattern more and more true. The game tries to balance the personalities.

Hope this helps!

(The same goes for Campers - If a villager you'd like to have in your town is at your Campsite, and you have less than 10 villagers, simply talk to them a few times and they'll eventually consider moving in. Sometimes they'll just need to be persuaded by you talking to them a few times, but some campers can be difficult and will force you to win a "game" in order for them to move in. However, you can continuously play these "games" until they finally agree to come.)

Answer (score 2):

Villagers the game gives you *normally* are totally random. Certain villagers "camp out" at the campsite and can be specifically enlisted to move in by pestering them over and over, but which villagers camp out is random (out of a set pool, I believe).

You can get specific villagers from other characters' towns, however, and this is the most consistent method of getting a specific villager (it is still not very consistent at all). If you visit a town there's a small chance one of the villagers of that town will move in to your town if you have an empty slot. I'm not sure what factors, if any, determine whether a villager will move in; presumably talking to the villager will help, but I'm not sure of this.

Comment: I believe that to get a villager from a friend's town, you have to connect on the date that the villager says he/she is going to move.

Comment: @JocelynHuang I had a villager move suddenly to a friends' town without mentioning it to me first. Not sure if it's a coincidence, but it happened to be the first move-away that happened without them going "oh hey I decided to move away Y/N?" beforehand