# Multiple of one villager?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I was actually wondering if it's possible to have two of the same villager on one island as I want Papi but my fiancé does too. I have one for her already as she doesn't like doing the online trading thing but someone is offering Papi for free. I have spent a good while looking online but unfortunately I have been unable to find an answer to this question and don't want to let this offer go to waste!

-edit

I would like to clarify, we both have our own switches and both want Papi, I am wondering if it's possible to have two of the same villager on my island at one time. One would go to my fiancés once she has a plot available and I would keep the other.

Comment: You may want to reword this a bit to clarify that you're playing on two Switches. The first time reading sounded like you meant 2 accounts on a single Switch.

Comment: Potentially related question: [How do I get a specific villager on my island?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128087/how-do-i-get-a-certain-villager)

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand this. Why do you each need your own Papi on the island? Can't you share the one? Edit: Oh, I see now, you're trying to get a second one on your island until you can give her one of them!

Comment: Whyare you trying to send the second papi to your island, instead of just using your fiancée's switch to get them to her island? Why the extra step?

Answer (score 1):

This question is moot?

1- If you are playing on the same switch, you automatically have the same island, and then the same villagers. If you want a duplicata of the same villager, I'm pretty sure that is not possible but I wonder what would happen if you try to invite him from another island. Probably it just doesn't offer you the option.

2- If you are on different switches, your islands do not have anything tieing them together. And villagers can be on different islands without problem. Only thing that might break immersion is that that villager you have will not recognise you if you encounter it on another island. You are basically meeting his long lost twin.

So in both cases, no problem. You and your SO can have the same villager.